# Write a function int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) which reads four arguments and returns the greatest of them

Tags: c, if-statement, max, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d);

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    
    return 0;
}

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a > b && a > c && a > d) {
        printf("%d\n", a);
    } else
    if (b > a && b > c && b > d) {
        printf("%d\n", b);
    } else
    if (c > a && c > b && c > d) {
        printf("%d\n", c);
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this question, we have to find out the greatest number among 4 numbers using functions. What is wrong with my code? Why it is not showing the correct output? Please tell me what I am doing wrong and please correct it.

Comment: You need `>=` not `>`

Comment: To properly understand the logic, you should also provide the values that you input into the program and show the output that you got. But most importantly, you should show the output that you *expected* and argue *why* you expected that. You would have likely caught your mistake here with not properly `return`ing a value.

Answer (score 3):

Your function `max_of_four` is not returning the maximum number, it's printing out a number and returning 0.

The logic of your code is also wrong in the case when some of the numbers are the same (perhaps you want `>=` rather than `>` to handle this).

As a hint, if you have a function `max(a, b)` which returns the maximum of two numbers, you can find the maximum of four numbers:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return max(max(a, b), max(c, d));
}
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

`Please tell me what I am doing wrong and please correct it.`

What's gone wrong is that you've tried to write intricate code that is too complicated.

Here's a very simple re-write of your function (returning the maximum of the 4 values to the caller.)

```
int max_of_four( int a, int b, int c, int d ) {
    int max = a;

    if( b > max ) max = b;
    if( c > max ) max = c;
    if( d > max ) max = d;

    return max;
}
```

Keep things simple and bugs have fewer chances to make you frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question title

> Write a function int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) which
> reads four arguments and returns the greatest of them

the function must return the maximum value but your function returns 0.

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover your function will output nothing if at least two arguments have the maximum value.

The function can look for example the following way.

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if ( !( a < b ) && !( a < c ) && !( a < d ) ) 
    {
        return a;
    } 
    else if ( !( b < c ) && !( b < d ) ) 
    {
        return b;
    } 
    else if ( !( c < d ) ) 
    {
        return c;
    } 
    else 
    {
       return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer here is the best one, according to me. But unfortunately I can't upvote it just yet.

Anyway, if you are writing a function to return the largest number among four numbers, it's a good idea to first declare a variable to store the maximum value, and initialize it to 0 (alternatively, you can also initialize it to the first number given to you).

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
  /* 
   Edit #1: Assigning the first value (among the four numbers) to 
   max is the best option. Please see below this code-box for 
   explanation. Thanks for pointing my mistake out, @Andrew Henle!
  */
  max = a; //this will store the largest value eventually
  if(b > max) //max is equal to "a" right now
    max = b;   
  /* 
    if b is greater than the value stored in max, then replace max with b.
    else, leave max as it is and proceed to the next line of code.
  */

  if(c > max) //max has the largest number among a & b right now
    max = c;
  if(d > max) //max has the largest number among a, b, and c
    max = d;

  return(max); //the largest value among a,b,c,d will be returned
}
```

> EDIT: I had initially assumed that you were asked to write that code
> for positive integers only. However, as [Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4756299/andrew-henle) pointed out,
> **max = 0** won't work for negative integers, because negative integers will always be less than 0. Hence, **max = a** is the best
> way to proceed. If **a** turns out to be the largest value, great! If
> not, then it'll eventually be replaced by other larger values, and
> **max** will store the largest number in the end. Thank you, Andrew! [Hey, that rhymes! :) ]
>
> The others have already pointed out your coding/logical errors, but here's a gist:

- Your function is returning **0** irrespective of what you write in the function, above **return 0;**
- Your function is unnecessarily printing some numbers when it should actually *return* a value. You're essentially assigning the return value to another variable, **ans**, right?

Comment: `max = 0; //this will store the largest value eventually`?? Oh?  `a = -1`, `b = -2`, `c = -3`, `d = -4`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! @AndrewHenle !